# Second Ajax call already populated with success results

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, javascript-objects

I have an Ajax call being made from a button press which returns me some data then goes off and creates a grid. The first time the function is called the Ajax call is made, data is returned and the grid is displayed. Happy Days.
However any subsequent call to the function, where none of the data parameters are changed, result in the Ajax call not being made to the server and the function skips straight to 'success' with the results from the successful call already populated.

Changing any of the 'postParameters' results in a successful Ajax call and the data is refreshed.

```
function btnClick(){
    //blah blah
    getGridData();
}

function getGridData() {
    var postParameters =
    {
        SiteID: "@Model.SiteID",
        DateFilterFrom: $("#datepickerFrom").val(),
        DateFilterTo: $("#datepickerTo").val(),
        CustomerFilter: $("#customers").val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("SalesForecast_Read", "Planning")",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: postParameters,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (results) {
            createHighlights(results.Highlights);
            createGrid(results.Entries);
        },
        error: function (e) {
            alert(e.responseText);
        }
    });
};
```

I know there must be an important Javascript concept I am missing but I just cant seem to be able to nail it.
Can anyone help put me in the right direction?

Comment: I think there is a cache problem here. There should be an option to ask specifically for no caching in the ajax query

Comment: Which is, in fact : `cache: false,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to disable the cache with:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("SalesForecast_Read", "Planning")",
    type: "GET",
    cache: false,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: postParameters,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (results) {
        createHighlights(results.Highlights);
        createGrid(results.Entries);
    },
    error: function (e) {
        alert(e.responseText);
    }
});
```

---

**Explanations**

The cache basically tries to save a call to the server by saving the return value of the calls.

It saves them using a hash of your query as a key, so if you make a second query that is identical, it will directly return the value from the cache, which is the value that was returned the first time.

If you disable it, it will ask the server for every query.

Answer (score 0):

try to add this in ur ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
  cache: false,
  //other options...
});
```

This will force the recall of the ajax each time. 
For more information please check the following link : 
[api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax)

Comment: What does it do? Any documentation on this? How does it help with the success results?

Comment: Obviously it will disable caching for the ajax request .. and will force the recall of the ajax each time.
And for more information please check the following link :
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Why don’t you edit your answer adding information? It will greatly improve the quality of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add cache: false to your ajax request.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("SalesForecast_Read", "Planning")",
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: postParameters,
    dataType: "json",
    cache:false,
    success: function (results) {
        createHighlights(results.Highlights);
        createGrid(results.Entries);
    },
    error: function (e) {
        alert(e.responseText);
    }
});
```

IE might not listen to you though. For that you can add a field to the POST Parameters, where you add the current time in miliseconds, so even IE does not cache.